# How are changes to the dashboard scoped?

Tags: control-panel, scope, cp-dashboard, dashboard

I'm working on a Craft project with another developer. We're connected to the same shared database but my dashboard is different than his (I customized mine).

This made us wonder how the custom dashboards are scoped. Are they based on user? Or are they based on a user group and "super admins" have their own individual scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Every user has their own unique dashboard.** The changes you make to your dashboard affect only your account.

It cannot be shared, and it cannot be preset in any way. It is not related to user groups at all. The only way to change someone else's dashboard is by logging into the control panel as an admin, then finding that user and "Log in as them".

There have been a handful of feature requests regarding pre-setting dashboards, or remotely controlling or locking another user's dashboard... but for the near future, this is simply how dashboards work.